# Typescript declaration Merging, how to unmerge?

Tags: typescript

I have the next Typescript declaration merging:

```
import { Collection, Entity, IEntity, OneToMany, PrimaryKey, Property } from "mikro-orm";
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";
import { LocationModel } from "./locationModel";

@Entity({ collection: "business" })
export class BusinessModel {
    @PrimaryKey()
    public _id!: ObjectId;

    @Property()
    public name!: string;

    @Property()
    public description!: string;

    @OneToMany({ entity: () => LocationModel, fk: "business" })
    public locations: Collection<LocationModel> = new Collection(this);
}

export interface BusinessModel extends IEntity<string> { }
```

Now, how can I unmerged them? To get a interface or data type equivalent to:

```
export interface BusinessEntity {
    _id: ObjectId;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    locations: Collection<LocationModel>; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to the types/decorators/modules you're using, so if any of the following yields errors you might consider  editing the code in the question to be a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

You can try to tease apart the types via something like

```
type BusinessEntity = 
  Pick<BusinessModel, Exclude<keyof BusinessModel, keyof IEntity<string>>>
```

but that will only work if `IEntity`'s keys don't overlap with the ones you added to `BusinessModel`.  A better idea would be to capture the type you care about *before* merging:

```
@Entity({ collection: "business" })
export class BusinessEntity {
  @PrimaryKey()
  public _id!: ObjectId;

  @Property()
  public name!: string;

  @Property()
  public description!: string;

  @OneToMany({ entity: () => LocationModel, fk: "business" })
  public locations: Collection<LocationModel> = new Collection(this);
}

export class BusinessModel extends BusinessEntity { }
export interface BusinessModel extends IEntity<string> { }
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Your solution works. But I finally I have chosen your suggestion, seems me more clear. Thanks.