# Get base interface when extending another interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

Suppose I have this simple interface:

```
interface IMyButton extends Partial<HTMLInputElement> {
  color?: string
}
```

This allows me to extend the base `HTMLInputElement` with properties definied in `IMyButton` (e.g. for web components).

Is there a way of getting only the properties that the base type, `IMyButton`, defines, rather than all the properties including the ones from `HTMLInputElement`?

So what I need is a new type that only has `color?: string` as a property.

The extended interface changes from component to component, i.e. `interface IMySelect extends Partial<HTMLSelectElement>`, so I can't just exclude a fixed type.

Some background why I need this: I have a mapped type that uses `IMyButton` - so using the API you have to define defaults for example. Right now this mapped type also includes `HTMLInputElement` properties, that are wholly optional and don't even need defaults. Visual Studio Code for example still shows all the properties of the extended type of course, so creating this object is really difficulty because the intellisense gets cluttered with base html properties...

Comment: This is similar to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55598680/2887218) I gave to someone trying to "unmerge" declarations.  The idea is the same: either do some kind of [`Omit`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30455) (type subtraction, which can be lossy) or redefine your interfaces to be what you want in the first place (which you've said you can't do)

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much already figured it out (assuming you can redefine your interfaces)

> So what I need is a new type that only has color?: string as a property.

Just make an interface that has the `color` property, then extend both:

```js
interface IMyButtonProps {
  color?: string
}

interface IMyButton extends IMyButtonProps, Partial<HTMLInputElement> {}
```

Comment: I know this is a possibility, but actually the definition of the interface is out of my control, so I can't do that.

Comment: Ahh yeah in that case I'm not sure